# Return True when subsequent array values match

Tags: python

I need to identify specific array values with subsequent matching values. In this example, I'd like to know when `B` is followed by two additional `B` values.

```py
arr = ['a', 'a', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'a']

desired_result == [False, False, True, False, False, False]
```

I saw another thread that suggests using `groupby()` to find matching values that are next to each other in an array. But it doesn't quite solve my problem, as it doesn't care if the matching values come before or after the array item.

```py
groupby_result = []
for k, g in groupby(arr):
    len_ = len(list(g))
    groupby_result += [len_ >= 3 and k == "B"] * len_ 

groupby_result == [False, False, True, True, True, False]
```

How might I achieve the `desired_result`?

Comment: Why do you not write a loop for `i` from 0 to `len(arr) - 3` and use `arr[i] == B and arr[i + 1] == B and arr[i + 2] == B`?

Comment: Have you tried to iterate your list and if the current item matches ``B`` you look at the next two items? Obviously only until you're at ``len(arr) -3``, otherwise looking up the next two items will raise index errors.

Comment: Is `arr` entirely composed of strings or arbitrary objects?

Comment: Also.. if you had `arr = [a,a,B,B,B,,B,a]` would the output be [False, False, True, True, False, False, False]` ?

Comment: Yes, arr is entirely composed of strings. 

arr = [a,a,B,B,B,,B,a] would be [False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False]

Thanks for the first two comments, feels cleaner than what I've been working on with groupby. I have it working and will post what I landed on shortly.

Comment: Why is the result not like @JonClements thought? How are you interpreting the double comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just a list comprehension?

```
[i < len(arr) - 2 and x == 'B' and arr[i+1:i+3] == ['B', 'B'] for i, x in enumerate(arr)]
```

Result:

```
[False, False, True, False, False, False]
```

We first test to ensure there *can be* two following values, then whether the current element is `'B'` then if both hold true, we compare the slice of the next two elements to `['B', 'B']`.

Comment: `[arr[i:i+3] == ['B']*3 for i in range(len(arr))]`

Answer (score 1):

One approach you could use is other `itertools` methods to create a sliding window.

```
from itertools import islice, tee, zip_longest

result = [
    all(k == 'B' for k in window) 
    for window in zip_longest(*[islice(i, n, None) 
    for n, i in enumerate(tee(arr, 3))])
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that loops through each item and checks to see if the next two items in the list are equivalent.  It checks to see if there are more than two items left in the list and returns False for the last two items:

```
mylist = ['a', 'a', 'B', 'B' ,'B' ,'a']
result = [
    all([
        val2 == val1
        for val2 in mylist[i + 1:i + 3]
    ]) if i < len(mylist) - 2 else False
    for i, val1 in enumerate(mylist)
]
```

Output:

```
[False, False, True, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.islice` and `zip` to line up the array against versions of itself offset by 1 and 2 positions:

```
from itertools import islice

arr = ['a','a','B','B','B','a']

res = [x == y == z == 'B' for x, y, z in zip(arr, islice(arr, 1, None), islice(arr, 2, None))] \
    + [False, False]  # The last two items can't possibly have two following matching items

print(res)
```

prints:

```
[False, False, True, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that is independent on the number of lookaheads - and can be adopted to fit any size of "runs" without having to modify the code itself. Iterates in reverse since you want to detect the first entry that has two following (if you want to mark those with two in front, don't reverse the list):

```py
mylist = ['a', 'a', 'B', 'B' ,'B' ,'a'][::-1]
prev = mylist[0]
counts = [0]  # start with a run count of 0

for idx in range(1, len(mylist)):
    counts.append((counts[idx - 1] + 1) if mylist[idx] == mylist[idx - 1] else 0)
    # if this entry was the same as the one in front, use the previous run count and increase with one

result = list(map(lambda x: x >= 2, counts))  # extract those that have at least 2 in run count (i.e. at least two identical before it)
print(result[::-1])  # reverse again
```

Output:

```py
[False, False, True, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = ['a', 'a', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'a']

# if x is the same as the next two values, then True:
out = [True if set(x) == set(arr[i+1:i+3]) 
               and len(arr[i+1:i+3]) == 2
               and x == 'B'
            else False 
       for i, x in enumerate(arr)]
print(out)

# Output:
[False, False, True, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

Staying close to your attempt ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZC/DoIwEMb3PsWFhVbroosxYWHwCdwMIRgKNpS2uZaBp8fyxwhGO9yXu/zuvi@1vX8afTpbHIYKTQvSC/TGKAeytQY91Gg6@@gJKRAhgXtcxBzmkm5LEWekFE6iKHMUrlN@5K@FcoLDIjfsPs1aMkIWp9VuRiqD0HCoQep3EhqCsAuB8JTQeeCCUCWdpzVj0/zr0j6caiBJIEqjDHZAp70DHP/Sc6SAtlJPNB9hYlHq4LLh2c/p6Lb9CzYMLw)):

```
groupby_result = []
for k, g in groupby(arr):
    len_ = len(list(g))
    groupby_result += [k == "B"] * (len_ - 2)
    groupby_result += [False] * min(len_, 2)
```

Or going backwards ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU@7DoMwDNz9Fd4AtZVKu1RIdGDoF3RDUZWKQCNBEjlh4OvTBFoBHvw4n@9kM7mPVtebIe9b0gNKJ8hp3VuUg9HksCM9mvcEwImwxDrhyRGXVO0TTxg0wkoSzYuEHXsX@Q/eW3HEX3nSuA7bwgCqQD9DqwklSoXEVSfSXqg0OGdZXRSnnBWAIWSLAaslw7KM5gsao8JDifk8iqC6XUTx2P0vA3THC4AhqdzssbZRd/9K5v0X)):

```
B = 0
for i in range(len(arr))[::-1]:
    if arr[i] == 'B':
        B += 1
    else:
        B = 0
    arr[i] = B > 2
```

As a list comp ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BC4JAFITv71fMTSWDrEsI28FDv6CbLLHhWgvqLm9X0F9vhpH5DvMxMG8YN4aX7U5nx9NUs21hguZgbeNhWmc54Mm2d4@RSDFDoIxUlGKRYisqklRpb1hXd9a@b8Inf1WN1ym@uHG/mn9IomKOH2j9jAvkAoMQcz1UV6HYZQkuOBJ@V1vGANNhXlfm@T6TcgGRY9OFeKlLNg5CYDs0maY3)):

```
B = 0
result = [(B := x=='B' and B+1) > 2
          for x in arr[::-1]][::-1]
```